When do we talk about spaghettification or pancakification in black holes?
So I've been doing some research for a while now, and yesterday came across the video of PBS space time talking about what happens to quantum information in a black hole. In the thought experiment about Bob and Alice, he does mention that when approaching the black hole, Alice doesn't get spaghettified but pancakified because of the small tidal forces of the black hole.
The argument is that indeed this black hole was so big that the difference in pull, at the human scale, was not great enough for her to experience spaghettification.
So now I came with a question, maybe a dumb one at it, but why does spaghettification appear so much more frequently than pancakification? I've personally never heard of pancakification, and is very triggering since the two phenomenas are quite extreme opposites.
So I thought that maybe, for ordinary scale black holes, spaghettification is the one phenomena happening, as opposed to supermassives black holes, that would be much bigger than ordinary ones. And so, since those black holes are less frequent, would be talked about as "special cases" of black holes, making the pancakification phenomena less talked about.
But since that is only a hypothesis, I don't know if it could also be tied to what black holes it is (such as kerr, Schwartzchild, [...]).
I also don't quite get the pancakification phenomena either, but i'll try to do some more research on the subject and ask another question later (I'm new at this, can we have two questions in the same post?)
I don't know much about the physics behind them either, I'm only in 12th grade, so I'd hope you could go easy on the mathematics, but any answer would help me a lot!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This article mentions "pancakification" as something that can happen to you once you have fallen sufficiently far into "realistic black holes, which are rotating and accreting matter." I didn't read it, so I can't say much more, but they made it sound as if you could expect be well spaghettified first, and then your spaghetti strand would be pancakified.

Pancakification seems to be a newer term. That could be why it's more rarely seen. We should probably be on the lookout now for all new research initiatives: swiss-rollification, pasta-screwification; pretzelification. There seems to be a hunger for this kind of knowledge.

@Wookie The actual reason is the official propaganda against the gravitational length contraction (“pancakification”). The gravitational equation is the Ricci tensor equals zero. This means the ttime dilation (“curvature” of time) equals the length contraction (“curvature” of space). And still the propaganda denies the obvious with the length contraction never mentioned anywhere. This makes people confused. Look at the answer of Yukterez where he mentions the time dilation instead of the length contraction.

@safesphere Right. Well, he's Viennese so it's probably wiener-breadification we're talking about now: increasingly thin layers of pastry surrounding a deliciously sticky jam hypercylinder. The link Yukterez provides to the Susskind lecture drops right in at length contraction though. Great minds think alike.

@Wookie - Since the term spaghettification is already established it is for the sake of consistency only logical to use the same syntax for the related pancakification.

@Wookie No, you’ve missed it. Suskind referred to the “Lorentz contraction”, which is due to the velocity of the falling object approaching the speed of light near the horizon. He never mentioned the gravitational length contraction. Not only does he strictly follow the official propaganda, but he is the main source of it. The gravitational length contraction is the most fascinating property of a black hole - while you are at the horizon, you see the horizon not as a thin shell, but as thick as the size of the universe. And then the next instant this entire “universe” is all at once inside.

@safesphere wrote: "while you are at the horizon, you see the horizon not as a thin shell, but as thick as the size of the universe" - wrong, when you fall in with the negative escape velocity (E=1) the gravitational depth expansion exactly cancels with the kinematic lorentz contraction in your frame (while in the external frame it gets squared), therefore the grr=1 in raindrop coordinates. Also it's not R/r=∞ but dR/dr=∞ in the stationary frame, if you integrate that from r1 to r2 you still get a finite distance.

@Yukterez Not wrong since I never mentioned a free fall. In an asymptotic hovering frame, the horizon thickness is arbitrarily large.  Also your integration procedure is not applicable. It calculates the distance traveled to get there, not the distance as observed from there. If you are remote and I hover progressively close to the horizon, in my frame the distance between us asymptotically diverges. However you at least admit the existence of "the gravitational depth expansion" (a.k.a. gravitational length contraction). This is already good enough :)

@safesphere - integrate $\rm \int_{r_s}^{r_1} {dr}/{\sqrt{1-{r_s}/{r}}}$ and you will see it is a finite distance, for example the expanded distance from the horizon at $\rm r=2$ to the photon sphere at $\rm r=3$ is $\rm \Delta R=3.04901$ instead of $3-2=1$ or $\infty$, so you could fit a longer rod between the two $\rm r$ than you'd naively expect by the difference in the circumference, but not an infinitely long one. The travelled distance on the other hand can also be simply $1$ if the velocity to get from $\rm r_1$ to $\rm r_2$ was the escape velocity, see the other comment above.

@safesphere - only the extremal Reissner Nordström and Kerr black hole with maximal charge or spin have an infinitely stretched horizon, see Bardeen 1972, Fig. 2, but with Schwarzschild or normal spinning black holes that is not the case.

Yes,the integral is indeed finite, but it doesn’t represent the distance in the hovering coordinates. It assumes variable $dr$, but in the hovering coordinates $dr$ is constant as defined by the metric at that $r$. Let me put it differently. Say you fall to a BH and then an asteroid falls to the same entry point from the 10 Gly distance. In my remote frame the asteroid ends up sub Planck length close to you. In your coordinates the asteroid always remains billions of light years away from you. Thus in my frame the near horizon slice is vanishingly thin, but in yours it is universe thick.

@Yukterez note that you don’t use an integral to describe the time dilation that diverges. You simply use the metric coefficient while the integral for the proper time is finite. It is the same with the length contraction. It is described by the metric coefficient that diverges while the integral for the proper distance is finite.

@safesphere - because that clock is at constant r you can use constant r, it doesn't need to change r to tick and since the metric is independent of time it is fine to just multiply the timespan with the constant factor to get the proper time of a clock at constant r. If the metric was time dependent you'd have to integrate that as well, but the ruler spans from one r to another, so you have to integrate from one r to the other since we are still dependent on r.

@Yukterez Sorry I am unable to explain the way you’d understand. The time dilation and length contraction are the metric coefficients for $dr$ and $dt$.  Both depend on $r$. If you can measure one at a particular $r$, then you can measure the other the same way. You are confusing two different values, the proper distance (length of the ruler) to that location and the distance in the coordinates of that location. The proper distance and proper time are both finite integrals. The time dilation and the length contraction are just the metric coefficients that both diverge (or vanish accordingly).

Susskind explains it here: the pancakification due to gravitational time dilation is only in the reference frame of Bob. In her own frame Alice gets spaghettified, not pancaked, since the local tidal forces are positive all the way.
On the left you have an infalling stream of particles with different initial velocities in ingoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates where you can see the local spaghettification, and on the right the same particles in the classic Schwarzschild-Droste coordinates where you can see the pancakification in the frame of the stationary coordinate bookkeeper:


The link Yukterez provides usefully covers length contraction as well as time dilation.

@Wookie No, it doesnt. See my detailed comment above.

@safesphere: in your mentioned comment above you claim that Sussind spouts some propaganda and is the source of a conspiracy to hide the gravitational depth expansion, but that's ridiculous. the real reason he focusses more on the grav. time dilation is that it is enough to explain the principle. the depth expansion is only needed quantitatively, not qualitatively, and since he didn't crunch the numbers in this video he did enough to mention it briefly. in the transverse direction you don't have gravitational expansion, and still all motions in the transverse directions also freeze at r=rs.

@safesphere: in the animations above the depth expansion is also taken into account, those use the equations of motion that come directly from the metric. In an animation where you show the specific coordinate times you need it all, but Susskind was just drawing a cartoon image on a blackboard without any specific numbers, so he did nothing wrong when he focussed on the more important part.

@safesphere: of course you're gonna say that the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates on the left are crap since you want the singularity as a one dimensional line or something, but for now you have to at least accept the animation on the right, since that uses the classical coordinates, which according to you are the only ones that are real.

In GR any coordinate system can be used. The problem is that the meaning of the coordinates is rarely understood. Even if you personally have a deep understanding of the EF coordinates, practically everyone looking at your diagrams assumes the classical view of apples falling down from the tree. So nothing but confusion and misinterpretation are created. The Schwarzschild diagram on the right side would be a lot more to the point if you dropped long bars and showed how they shrink in length. The way it is the diagram shows the time dilation, but the length contraction is not evicent.

"in the transverse direction you don't have gravitational expansion" - Well, how about the Susskind "complementarity principle? "An infalling observer will see the point of entry of the information as being localized on the event horizon, while an external observer will notice the information being spread out uniformly over the entire stretched horizon" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_complementarity

@safesphere - 1) I could use long rods too, but then I'd have to choose some arbitrary rigidity for them, so I leave it to the observer to connect the dots. 2) that is quantum woohoo, while this thread is in the category general relativity.

For the purposes of illustrating the length contraction you could neglect the tidal forces, such as assuming a SMBH or equivalently the absolute rigidity. On the second part, it is not completely quantum. For example, when a classical electric charge approaches the horizon, its electric field becomes spherically symmetric centered on $r=0$, but not on the point of entry.

@safesphere - that would just be the top view of Flamm's paraboloid with an equidistant circle grid, I've already done that where it was in context. Here the question is about tidal forces though, so assuming absolute rigidity would be offtopic.

I watched the video, and it's important to note that the term pancakification is not used anywhere else at all. However, it is interesting to see what the video tries to say. Without going too deep into general relativity, the effect can be explained purely Newtonian as well. I will keep the mathematics as simple as possible. Say we have Alice of mass $m_A$ and length $L_A$, then the Newtonian difference in force between her head and her feet will be:
\begin{equation}
\Delta F = \frac{GMm_A}{r^2} - \frac{GMm_A}{(r+L_A)^2}
\end{equation}
with $M$ the mass of the black hole. The idea of 'spaghettification' is now that this difference will be so large, that  her head will inevitably be pulled apart from her feet. We can rewrite the force difference as:
\begin{equation}
\Delta F = \frac{GMm_A}{r^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{2L_A}{r}+\frac{L_A^2}{r^2}}\right)
\end{equation}
with $L_A\ll r$, so the denominator terms are almost zero. We can make a taylor expansion to estimate the behaviour. Know that for small $x$, $\frac{1}{1+x}\approx 1-x+\ldots$, so we have:
\begin{equation}
\Delta F \approx \frac{GMm_A}{r^2}\left(1-1+\frac{2L_A}{r}\right) = \frac{2GMm_AL_A}{r^3}
\end{equation}
where I ignored quadratic terms due to being too small. Let's evaluate this approximation for the force difference at the event horizon/ Schwartzschild radius $r = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$:
\begin{equation}
\Delta F \approx \frac{2GMm_AL_A}{\frac{8G^3M^3}{c^6}} = \frac{m_Ac^6L_A}{4G^2M^2}
\end{equation}
Even in this Newtonian approximation we can see what's going on. First of all, if Alica is longer ($L_A$ is bigger), the force difference will evidently be larger. Secondly, at the event horizon, we see that the force difference scales as $\sim 1/M^2$: the larger the black hole, the less spaghettification we have, simply because the event horizon distance is much farther away. Indeed for these super massive black holes the spaghettification process will not occur (to properly calculate the effect, you would need general relativistic calculations of course).
The idea of 'pancakification' is now that since objects seem to freeze at the event horizon, for an outside observer (Bob) Alice looks to be located in a very thin slice right before the event horizon. In some sense, she looks as a pancake, compressed into that thin slice. Bear in mind that this is only what Bob would see, from Alice's perspective she only feels a slightly stronger pull at her feet than on her head (see derivation above).
